# Why should I explicitly make an operation atomic?

Tags: multithreading, caching, synchronization, parallel-processing, atomic

Consider the following code:

```
int x=0;

#pragma omp parallel num_threads(4) default(none) shared(x)
 {
  for(int i=0; i<1000; ++i)
   x++;
 }
cout << x << endl;
```

The expected out put is 4000. However what I usually see is something between 2500-3500. I already know why, (because I didn't make this operation atomic). Until today I thought this was totally acceptable, but then something came to my mind:

> Cache coherency protocols are supposed to keep data consistent among
>   cores. That is, if a core wants to write to a variable, it must first
>   gain exclusive access to it, and then proceed with write operation.

Now i'm wondering why would I get any result other than 4000, even
   when I don't specify it's an atomic operation?

One thing that comes to my mind is that maybe when the code is compiled into machine code it possibly create two copies of x.

**EDIT:**
What I think of cache coherency protocols is explained in the following figure taken from [here](http://csl.cs.ucf.edu/~heinrich/papers/Dissertation.pdf)(Page 19):
[image: Get Exclusive]
Now **I know** this figure is for a multi-processor(and not multi-core) systems using bit-vector protocol, but I think something close to this is used in Intel processors that are using MESI protocol. If this is true, then the reader won't get a copy of requested value until all invalidations are acknowledged. Correct me if I'm wrong. I've tried searching for details of how MESI protocol works, but I haven't found much.

Comment: The interaction issues with multi-processor are the same as those of multi-core. The problem has to do with how many "execution units" there are that (potentially) may access a memory location simultaneously. A memory lock forces other units potentially contending for a memory location to back off until the locker has completed working with the location.

Comment: @OlofForshell, in my opinion (correct me if I'm wrong), there should be no simultaneous write access to same location on hardware/protocol level. I know what the lock does, but I think the protocol does this before hand in hardware. Do you know any resources that show otherwise? You and others claim that there's still a possibility that processors/cores may simultaneously access but yet show no references to confirm. I'd appreciate anything.

Answer (score 4):

I agree 100% with Gray's answer. However, the non-atomicity of increment is a known issue and it's not just applicable to multi-cores, as it can just as well occur on a single core machine.

The fact is that `x++` is (usually) actually accomplished through several assembler instructions, for example:

```
load r,[x]  ; load memory into register
incr r       ; increment register
stor [x],r  ; store register back to memory
```

so although it's a single operation in the C program, it's actually a non-atomic sequence of assembler instructions that can be interrupted at any point. So even on a single core machine, a thread might be interrupted before completing the increment, thus leaving the variable in an inconsistent state.

Some compilers or architectures may indeed treat increment as atomic, but it's not a good idea to assume this.

Comment: How can I know which instructions are used for x++? Is there a tool to reads executable and display assembly code?

Comment: Well usually a debugger can do that for you. For example on linux you can open your executable with gdb and use the disassemble command to view the assembler instructions of the program.

Comment: There is a C keyword (register) to request that a variable, if possible, be stored in a register. However, since it is not a guarantee that it will, the method you show is most probably how it is done many times.

Comment: Tudor is spot on but to be sure @AtoMerZ, he is talking about atomic with regards to the local cache -- not to central memory or another processor's cache.  Just because something is atomic does not imply any degree of synchronization.

Comment: Many modern compilers ignore the `register` keyword @Eduardo because their internal register allocators are better than you are at optimizing.

Comment: @Gray: yes, of course. My example was just illustrate how, even if one suggests it is register, it may not be and, therefore, it will not be atomic for sure.

Answer (score 2):

Why do you think that the value `x` is stored in a coherent cache location?  Each core has it's own cache memory but there are no guarantees of coherency between those caches unless you ask for them.  And there is no guarantee about the *order* of the cache updates -- nor the frequency.  One thread could add 100 to x and then the cache could be synchronized overwriting the other thread's increment of 20.

The first time `x` is referenced, it gets pulled into a processor (or core) memory cache from central memory.  Most likely each thread will get a 0 the first time.  But it may be at the very end of the loop that anything is written back to central memory and each thread might easily write back 1000 to `x`.  There is certainly no guarantees that `x` will be updated with each `x++` -- either written or re-read.  In fact, you are pretty much guaranteed that `x` will *not* be updated each time unless it is synchronized. In terms of this tight loop, `x` will never be evicted from the cache so it will never be re-read automatically.  Even if it wasn't such a tight loop, making some guess about when `x` will be evicted would be extremely hard to do -- even if you were always working on the same hardware.

Lastly, the word really is "synchronization" instead of "atomic".   `x++` is rarely an atomic operation these days (it is actually read, increment, store) but it certainly is not synchronized between cache memory locations or central storage.

Comment: So cache coherency protocols are used if the programmer asks for them? I thought cache was invisible to the programmer.

Comment: `There is certainly no guarantees that x will be updated with each x++`. If so, then what's the point of cache coherency protocols? They're there to keep data consistent, aren't they?

Comment: The cache _is_ invisible to the programmer but the synchronization of those caches is not.   If every value was updated from central memory each time it was written then there's no point in having a cache.  The entire point is to cache central memory -- even when writing.  What the programmer needs to know how to do is to use the language definition to put synchronization points where necessary.

Comment: The point of cache coherency is that when you do a synchronization, it takes care of it for you.  I knows which memory blocks are dirty and need to be flushed and which to write back to central core.  It's magic but it's not 100% invisible otherwise it would never know when you was a fresh copy of `x` and when the cache version is fine.

Comment: Good answer. Another fact is that x++ is actually accomplished through several assembler instructions, so although it's a single operation in the C program, it's actually a non-atomic sequence of assembler instructions that can be interrupted at any point.

Comment: Agreed, with many architectures but on some it actually is an atomic operation -- or at least it was.  At least there is still increment register operations at the assembly level but maybe even those aren't atomic at the processor runtime operation.  I've tweaked my answer.  Thanks @Tudor.

Comment: I have problem with the part quoted in my second comment. To make things clear I updated my question to reflect my thoughts. If you can provide any references/links on details of today's cache coherency protocols that explain thing  like the figure i posted, I'd appreciate that.

Comment: The paper is about distributed system shared memory protocols.  If you want to ask about that then I'd post another question.  You can't keep on editing the same question until you get the answer you like @AtoMerZ.  I stand by my answer.  Good luck.

Comment: @Tudor: an increment instruction of the form "inc mem" is atomic in that the processor executing it can't be interrupted in the middle of it - it has to complete first. The issue being discussed here is whether the instructions access to the memory (RAM) location is atomic which, at least on an x86, it isn't. Atomicity may be achieved on an x86 memory access by using the lock prefix. This is the mechanism used by memory barriers, spinlocks, critical regions or whatever you choose to call them.

Comment: @Olof Forshell: I was not talking about "inc mem", I was talking about the C instruction `i++`, which is on a different level.

Comment: @Tudor: it is not a fact that the C statement x++ "is actually accomplished through several assembly instructions," not if we're talking x86. It MAY be accomplished that way but may just as well be the result of a single "inc mem" or "add mem,1" or such. If we're talking RISC however, you're probably right. Some compilers have locked increment/decrement intrinsics for cases requiring atomicity.

Answer (score 1):

Cache coherency means that as soon as one core (or a bus mastering device) writes to a memory location that location is invalidated in other (all) caches that contain it. This forces them to reload the location (in the form of a 64-byte cache line) before they can access it (R or W) the next time.

So cache coherency is not data coherency it's just a guarantee that an updated location will be invalidated asap. Caches can't do more, they're always way behind the executing cores and somewhat behind each other. If one core updates a location and another does the same slightly later both caches concerned will think their location is valid (and they will both probably invalidate each other's cache lines).

What kind of a guarantee is this if the data isn't guaranteed to be valid? It's the best that can be done under the circumstances. The choice is between completely synchronized cores (which would run exceedingly slowly) and running at full speed with caches (with specific, defined consequences and working solutions to handle them). The solutions are essentially very short slowdowns such that everything is synchronized afterwards. These intermittent, very short slowdowns should be weighed against the permanent slowdown of fully synchronized cores.

Under normal circumstances there is no contention over the same location from different cores or bus-mastering devices. But once they begin to share certain memory locations the solutions provided allow the programmer to make sure that the necessary synchronization can be implemented.

[This seems like a pretty good paper on caches](http://research.cs.wisc.edu/multifacet/theses/michael_marty_phd.pdf) ... [and this](http://www.rdrop.com/users/paulmck/scalability/paper/whymb.2010.06.07c.pdf).

Edit: to be more precise on cache coherency: when a core writes to a location its own cache system will first make sure that the pertinent cache information in the caches of other cores is invalidated. So after a write only the cache of the core that wrote to the location will contain cached data about the location.

Comment: Thanks for the links. I understand that you mean the overhead of synchronization is too much to be used on every transaction. So instead the burden is on the programmer to use it as needed.

Comment: You probably need synchronization for every transaction but the trick is making the time required as short as possible. Also, when I looked in the intel x86 documentation they mention that the lock signal needn't necessarily need to leave the cache system resulting in a much faster lock.

Comment: Synchronization can be as simple as doing a lock, setting a bool in the structure member in question (being_processed=TRUE) and clearing the lock. Other threads wanting to process will pass it over simply by reading the bool and backing off (if they see the bool is cleared they enter the locking sequence described to get exclusive access). When the processing is finished the thread that did the processing simply clears the bool (the locking sequence is unnecessary there).